# How do I display a custom dialog box from a function?

Tags: android, dialog

In my app, I have three menu options that call functions.  One of the three calls a function that is supposed to read some info from a file and then display it in a dialog box.  My problem is getting the dialog box to work. I am using http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application
as a reference, but the methods they used do not work for me.

The part between the lines of asterisks is where I am getting an error.  The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})" It goes on to list suggested alternatives, which give the same error but list setOnClickListener as a suggested alternative.  I get another error after the override: "The method onClick(View) of type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method"

There has to be an easy way to accomplish this task?  Am I missing something that should be obvious?

```
//now stick it in a dialog box
        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Totals");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.diagtext1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.diagtext2);
        TextView text3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.diagtext3);
        Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
        text1.setText(dist);
        text2.setText(time);
        text3.setText(speed);
        //******************************************************
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                finish();
            }

        });
        //******************************************************
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` to get rid of the first error.

Remove the `@Override` before the `onClick()` method. `View.OnClickListener` declares `onClick()` as `abstract void` so there is no implementation to override.

The `finish()` call in the `onClick()` method will close your activity/app if there's only one Activity running. You may want to use `dialog.dismiss()` or `dialog.cancel()` instead.

Comment: I changed the things you suggested.  It compliles, but crashes when dialog.show() is called.  The exact error is: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:Unable to add window -- token null is not for an app..."  Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Success!  That error comes from using `Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
     final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);`  To fix it, just do `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Mark/Comment Button 'btn' and try add negative button.

```
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Quit", new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            finish();
        }

    });
```

Hopefully help you.